# Calculus Question in a Mock Undergraduate Entrance Examination

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, contest-math

I saw the following question:

> Prove that any real number $\alpha\ge\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$ can be expressed in the form: $$\alpha=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}^3}$$ where $a_0,a_1,a_2,...$ is an increasing sequence of real numbers with $a_0=1$.

Since this was on a mock test for an undergraduate entrance examination, in theory, this question should be doable with basic calculus. But, given that only one person who wrote the test attempted this question (and got $0/10$), I don't think this is the case with this question. I have no idea how to do this, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Solutions on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2345623p18954726, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2579216p22188460

Comment: @MartinR woah it's crazy that so many of the test takers missed such a simple and elegant solution, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Infinite sum](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2579216p22188460) on AoPS: It suffices to consider sequence of the form $a_n = t^n$ with $t > 1$. For these sequences is
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}^3} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{n+1}}{t^{3n}} = \frac{t^3}{t^2-1} =: f(t) \, .
$$
Now show that $\min\limits_{t > 1} f(t) = 3 \sqrt 3/2$ and conclude that for every $\alpha \ge 3 \sqrt 3/2$ there is a $t > 1$ such that $f(t) = \alpha$.

*Remark:* One can also show (see [number that can be written as a certain series](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2345623p18954726) on AoPS) that this bound is sharp: For any increasing sequence $(a_n)$ with $a_0 = 1$ is
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}^3} \text{ divergent or }
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}^3} \ge \frac{3 \sqrt 3}{2} \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks, this is an exceedingly simple and elegant answer.